# Hudson Sonar error

Tags: sonarqube, hudson

I am using Hudson 3.1.0 version and sonar 3.7.4 version. SInce yesterday I am getting this weird error while doing sonar analysis:

[image: sonarhudson error]

This was working fine until yesterday. sonar-maven-plugin-3.3.0.603 version is used.Can somebody help here?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a version of the SonaQube Scanner for Maven that is too recent (3.3.0.603). You should lock this version (in your POM) to an older version to make sure this keeps on working correctly.

As a side note, please consider upgrading to more recent software:

- SonarQube 3.7.4 is 4 years old and no more supported (which means nobody will help you in case of trouble)
- Hudson is kind-of dead - the best option for you is to move on Jenkins

Comment: Thanks..I will discuss with Team for up gradation. But for time being what version of sonar-maven-plugin should I lock down in pom to make this working?